# Use variable in nexusArtifactUploader/Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have this Jenkins DSL script which gets the version from pom.xml file and uses that version in nexusArtifactUploader. This is currently not working and I am getting **"groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: version for class: groovy.lang.Binding"** error. I am new to Groovy/Jenkins DSL  and don't know how to make it work.

```
stage('Nexus') {
        steps {
            script {
                def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
                echo pom.version

                nexusArtifactUploader(
                        nexusVersion: 'nexus3',
                        protocol: 'http',
                        nexusUrl: 'nexus.example.com:8080/nexus',
                        groupId: 'com.example',
                        **version: "${pom.version}",**
                        repository: 'example',
                        credentialsId: 'ciuser',
                        artifacts: [
                            [artifactId: 'com.example',
                            file: 'com.example-' + version + '.jar',
                            type: 'jar']
                        ]
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error is actually on this line:

```
file: 'com.example-' + version + '.jar',
```

Try replacing `version` with `pom.version`.

Comment: Thanks for the message. Let me try that.